# How to delete text between a character and linebreak in Notepad++

Tags: regex

I need to remove text between the character  `?` and linebreak; and if it's possisble for the question  mark, to be removed as well.

Comment: try: `\?[^\r\n]+$`

Answer (score 0):

You shold achieve this with a simple `(.*\?).+$`, replacing this for `$1`. The dollar matches the end of line when using the multi line matching.
[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/HZ56qc/1)

Comment: yous, maches `?`at the end, NOT between it and end.

Comment: i will edit the answer